# How to get list of value of particular node of partially XML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have following string. I don't know whether I call it XML format or not. That's why I have used the word partially XML. Please correct me if I have used wrong terminology.

```
<grid name=\"resultset\" object=\"1\" jump=\"name\" select=\"1\" icon=\"1\" preview=\"1\">
    <row name=\"result\" id=\"accountid\">
        <cell name=\"name\" width=\"300\" />
        <cell name=\"telephone1\" width=\"100\" />
        <cell name=\"primarycontactid\" width=\"150\" />
        <cell name=\"accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1\" width=\"150\" disableSorting=\"1\" />
        <cell name=\"statecode\" width=\"100\" />
    </row>
</grid>
```

I want to get values of `name` attribute from `cell` tag `i.e name, telephone1, primarycontactid, accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1, statecode`

Can anybody suggest me how to get above values using javascript or jquery?

Error after applying following cocept: This happens if number of elements are more

```
var str = "<grid name=\"resultset\" object=\"1\" jump=\"name\" select=\"1\" icon=\"1\" preview=\"1\"><row name=\"result\" id=\"accountid\"><cell name=\"name\" width=\"300\" /><cell name=\"telephone1\" width=\"100\" /><cell name=\"primarycontactid\" width=\"150\" /><cell name=\"accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1\" width=\"150\" disableSorting=\"1\" /><cell name=\"statecode\" width=\"100\" /></row></grid>";

var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = str;

var cells = tmpDiv.getElementsByTagName('cell')
var values = [];

for(var i = 0; i<cells.length; i++) {
  values.push(cells[i].getAttribute('name'));
}
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: It is store in a variable ? or in the DOM ?

Comment: @SteevePitis It stores in a string variable.

Comment: You're going to have tell us what it is specifically to be able to parse it, otherwise it's just invalid markup.

Comment: @adeneo As I said in question that it is in string. I also said I don't know what it call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "<grid name=\"resultset\" object=\"1\" jump=\"name\" select=\"1\" icon=\"1\" preview=\"1\"><row name=\"result\" id=\"accountid\"><cell name=\"name\" width=\"300\" /><cell name=\"telephone1\" width=\"100\" /><cell name=\"primarycontactid\" width=\"150\" /><cell name=\"accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1\" width=\"150\" disableSorting=\"1\" /><cell name=\"statecode\" width=\"100\" /></row></grid>";

var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = str;

var cells = tmpDiv.getElementsByTagName('cell')
var values = [];

for(var i = 0; i<cells.length; i++) {
  values.push(cells[i].getAttribute('name'));
}
              
console.log(values);
```

I think this is what you want.
You can also do a regex search.

**REGEX**

```js
var str = "<grid name=\"resultset\" object=\"1\" jump=\"name\" select=\"1\" icon=\"1\" preview=\"1\"><row name=\"result\" id=\"accountid\"><cell name=\"name\" width=\"300\" /><cell name=\"telephone1\" width=\"100\" /><cell name=\"primarycontactid\" width=\"150\" /><cell name=\"accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1\" width=\"150\" disableSorting=\"1\" /><cell name=\"statecode\" width=\"100\" /></row></grid>";

var reg = /<cell name=[\\]?"([^\\"]*)[^>]*>/mgi;

var item;
while ((item = reg.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(item[1]);
}
```

Comment: I had tested your code when I had very few element. Now I have 50 elements. It throws error. I have edited my question and show the screenshot. Please suggest.

Comment: Enjoy IE :D, btw it crashes with only 50 cells ? can you log `cells.length` before the loop ?

Comment: It's Firefox and this throws frequently if cells are more. Cell is actually field name of table. It can be more than 50 cells. If I comment that code, it works fine. Please suggest.

Comment: Your browser have some limitations ... but it can handle easily 10 000 cells (it is a bit laggy ... but it works), if you have more than 10 000 I suggest to do this on your server

Comment: I have updated my answer and proposed the regex version, maybe it is more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Create element from string, then access children and their properties:

```js
var node = '<grid name="resultset" object="1" jump="name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1"><row name="result" id="accountid"><cell name="name" width="300" /><cell name="telephone1" width="100" /><cell name="primarycontactid" width="150" /><cell name="accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid.emailaddress1" width="150" disableSorting="1" /><cell name="statecode" width="100" /></row></grid>';
document.body.innerHTML = node;
var grid = document.getElementsByTagName('grid');
alert(grid[0].getAttribute('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
       var strcurrname= document.getElementsByTagName("cell")[i].name;
}
```

try this..

Comment: Thank you but you might misunderstand. The value(data) is stored in string. Also note that it is not fixed up to 5. Please suggest how to get from string.